# How to send information through redirect but hide it in the URL?

Tags: php, yii

I am sending information to a view like this:

```
$this->redirect('/user/view?message='. urlencode($myMessage));
```

In the view I get the message but the url shows the content of the message. **How can I hide it?**

```
$message = $_GET['message'];
```

output:

```
user/view?message=This+is+my+message
```

Comment: Why not send it in a post, store it in the session maybe? Some other super-global? `$_GET` isn't the best way to send info that you don't want to show.

Comment: How would I post if all I know is that I am redirecting to a page named `/user/view`?

Comment: @Andrew — You can't make an HTTP redirect that results in a POST request.

Comment: @Quentin I'm aware of that, I was just suggesting something else...in all fairness $_POST wasn't the best suggestion ever, it was there to make a point.

Comment: Is the goal to hide it for *user experience* or *security*? If it's ux then a cookie would suffice; if it's for security then use the session or nonce-backed server side storage.

Comment: @user2864740 yeah, it is for user experience.

Comment: @J_Strauton Then cookies (~4k limit/per) or server-persisted (with nonce in url or via session). Or, if a redirect can be avoided there is no need to persist across requests.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->render('/user/view',array(
        'message'=>$message,
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setFlash`](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/) to do that.

In your controller:

```
// Set flash
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('message', 'This is your message');
// ...and make redirect without including message in url
$this->redirect('/user/view');
```

And in redirected page view file:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('message')): ?>
    <div class="message">
        <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('message'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks!